# "Failed to build BatchDataset" after migrating from Tensorflow v1 to Tensorflow v2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to migrate a preexisting model from old Tensorflow v1 code to Tensorflow v2 for use in a project that depends on newer Tensorflow and Python versions. After applying the automatic migration script and disabling eager execution I am stuck with the error

`Detected at node 'ds/initializer' defined at (most recent call last): Node: 'ds/initializer' AddDataset: Failed to build BatchDataset op with error More Input() calls than the 2 input_args while building NodeDef 'BatchDataset/_14' using Op<name=BatchDataset; signature=input_dataset:variant, batch_size:int64 -> handle:variant; attr=output_types:list(type),min=1; attr=output_shapes:list(shape),min=1; attr=metadata:string,default=""> [[{{node ds/initializer}}]]`

This is the full stack trace:
[Stacktrace screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv4ik.png)

The error occurs in this line:

```py
self.sess.run(
            self.init,
            feed_dict={
                self.x: frames,
                self.y: labels,
                self.ph_n_shuffle: 1,
                self.ph_n_repeat: 1,
                self.ph_n_batch: n_batch if n_batch > 0 else frames.shape[0],
            },
        )
```

The shapes and values of all values in `feed_dict` remained the same after migrating. Printing `self.init` I get:

```
name: "ds/initializer"
op: "MakeIterator"
input: "ds/BatchDataset_1"
input: "ds/Iterator"
attr {
  key: "_class"
  value {
    list {
      s: "loc:@ds/Iterator"
    }
  }
}
experimental_type {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not well versed in pure Tensorflow without Keras and found no information relating to this problem on Google. Mind that executing the model on the same data using Tensorflow v1 and Python 3.6 works fine.

If relevant, I am trying to execute this code using Python 3.10.11 and Tensorflow 2.12.0.

I already tried analyzing the shapes and datatypes of all values in feed_dict. They remained the same after migration.
I also asked ChatGPT for help which mentioned that
`This error message indicates that there was a problem building a BatchDataset operator in TensorFlow due to an inconsistency in the number of input arguments provided to the operator. More specifically, the error message is saying that the BatchDataset operator was called with more input arguments than expected. The BatchDataset operator is designed to take two input arguments: an input_dataset (of type variant) and a batch_size (of type int64). However, the error message indicates that more than two input arguments were provided to the operator, which caused the build to fail. To fix this error, you should check the code where you are using the BatchDataset operator and ensure that you are only passing the two expected input arguments. You should also verify that the data types of the input arguments match the expected types.`

However, as the code above has not been changed and the datatypes and shapes remained the same I could not fix the issue using this advice.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Interestingly, printing self.init using old python and tensorflow I get
```
name: "ds/initializer"
op: "MakeIterator"
input: "ds/BatchDataset_1"
input: "ds/Iterator"
attr {
  key: "_class"
  value {
    list {
      s: "loc:@ds/Iterator"
    }
  }
}
```
Which seems to be the same except `experimental_type { type_id: TFT_PRODUCT }` is missing.